# ImageMagick: Zoom an image by integral zoom factor without any smoothing?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have a 256×256 PNG image in `a.png` that just consists of black and white pixels.

What I want is just to zoom it by a factor of 4, so that each pixel becomes a 4×4 block of the same color.  So what I did is:

`> convert a.png -geometry 1024x1024 a4.png`

The problem is that the resulting image `a4.png` is blurred and is no more 2-colored black-and-white.

**What does not work:**

- With `-colors 2` I am getting an output with only 2 colors, but they are grey-ish, not black + white.  And the image looks dithered even with `-dither none`.
- `-dither none` has no effect.
- `-quantize-colorspace` has no effect.
- `-solarize 128` has no effect either.
- `-depth 1` does not work (shreds the image).

Thanks in advance for any hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
convert input.png -scale 1024x1024 result.png
```

Comment: Or if he wants it scaled 4x, then `convert input.png -scale 400x400% result.png`