# ImageMagick: Zoom SVG and convert it to PNG?

Tags: svg, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have the following 8×8 SVG graphic for which I want a scaled version of as PNG. (I found no way to upload SVG so you can see it.)  The SVG consist of 8×8 black/white "pixels".

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="8" height="8" viewBox="0 0 8 8">
<path fill="#fff" d="M0,0H8V8H0"/>
<path fill="#000" d="M0,0H7V1H6V0H5V3H8V2H7V5H6V5H6V4H8V6H7V8H8V7H1V8H2V5H3V6H4V7H5V4H2V1H3V2H4V3H1V4H0"
fill-rule="evenodd"/>
</svg>
```

When I am using [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org)'s

`> convert a3x2.svg -scale 80x80 a3x2.png`

as of [this answer for scaling a PNG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75340965/1556746), then I am getting the following result which has nothing to do with the input:

[image: result of conversion]

What I want is a scaled black/white PNG where each pixel has a "size" of 10×10; no smoothing or dithering.  What does not work is `-resize 80x80` (will blur and still has wrong pixel values).

---

**Edit**

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14174624/1556746), a solution with Inkscape is

`> inkscape -w 80 -h 80 a3x2.svg -o a3x2.png`

which works, but I'd rather use ImageMagick.  For reference, here is the result with Inkscape so you can see that the result of `convert` from above is not as expected.

[image: PNG Result with Imagemagick]

`> convert -version`

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.10-23 Q16 x86_64 20190101 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2019 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC Modules OpenMP 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib djvu fftw fontconfig freetype jbig jng jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png tiff webp wmf x xml zlib
```

---

**Edit 2**

As asked in a comment, here is the result of

`> convert -verbose a3x2.svg txt:`

```
'inkscape' '/tmp/magick-445746DLWe3-eb4nrF' --export-filename='/tmp/magick-445746FrMsKiicip2C' --export-dpi='96,96' --export-background='rgb(100%,100%,100%)' --export-background-opacity='1' > '/tmp/magick-445746cd-3Bn1wlmb8' 2>&1
mvg:/tmp/magick-445746UpfR0goE2RRA=>/tmp/magick-445746UpfR0goE2RRA MVG 8x8 8x8+0+0 16-bit sRGB 445B 0.000u 0:00.000
a3x2.svg MVG 8x8 8x8+0+0 16-bit sRGB 445B 0.000u 0:00.000
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 8,8,65535,srgba
0,0: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
1,0: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
2,0: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
3,0: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
4,0: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
5,0: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
6,0: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
7,0: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
0,1: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
1,1: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
2,1: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
3,1: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
4,1: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
5,1: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
6,1: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
7,1: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
0,2: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
1,2: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
2,2: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
3,2: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
4,2: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
5,2: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
6,2: (61439,61439,61439,65535)  #EFFFEFFFEFFFFFFF  srgba(94%,94%,94%,1)
7,2: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
0,3: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
1,3: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
2,3: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
3,3: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
4,3: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
5,3: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
6,3: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
7,3: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
0,4: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
1,4: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
2,4: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
3,4: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
4,4: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
5,4: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
6,4: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
7,4: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
0,5: (65535,65535,65535,65535)  #FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF  white
1,5: (61439,61439,61439,65535)  #EFFFEFFFEFFFFFFF  srgba(94%,94%,94%,1)
2,5: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  blaca3x2.svg=> MVG 8x8 8x8+0+0 16-bit sRGB 445B 0.000u 0:00.000
k
3,5: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
4,5: (61439,61439,61439,65535)  #EFFFEFFFEFFFFFFF  srgba(94%,94%,94%,1)
5,5: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
6,5: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
7,5: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
0,6: (65535,65535,65535,65535)  #FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF  white
1,6: (65535,65535,65535,65535)  #FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF  white
2,6: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
3,6: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
4,6: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
5,6: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
6,6: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
7,6: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
0,7: (65535,65535,65535,65535)  #FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF  white
1,7: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
2,7: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
3,7: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
4,7: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
5,7: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
6,7: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
7,7: (0,0,0,65535)  #000000000000FFFF  black
```

Comment: **ImageMagick** seems to be fundamentally misunderstanding your SVG. It is nothing to do with the resizing. You can see it only produces 5 white pixels if you do `convert IMAGE.SVG txt:` Maybe the delegates are wrong. Try `convert -verbose IMAGE.SVG txt:` and see if it is using MVG, or rsvg, or inkscape. Click [edit] and paste the output into your question rather than the comments please.

Comment: @Mark Setchell: Thanks, I added the output to the question as **Edit 2**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mmmm... I don't know what's going on, but I can confirm that if I use the `rsvg` delegate in place of the MVG delegate, I get the correct result:

[image]

I find it simplest to use the docker `alpine` image to demonstrate because it is very current and has an extensive set of delegates without any user configuration. So, I just did:

```
# Start latest alpine image, bind mounting current working directory to /work
docker run -it -v "$(pwd)":/work alpine

apk update && apk add imagemagick

identify -version
Version: ImageMagick 7.1.0-52 Q16-HDRI aarch64 20549 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: (C) 1999 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI Modules 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib cairo fontconfig freetype gslib heic jng jpeg jxl lcms ltdl lzma png ps rsvg tiff webp x xml zlib
Compiler: gcc (12.2)

magick image.svg -scale 80x80 result.png
```

Comment: Updating from 6.9 to 7.1 did the trick for me, so marking this one as the soluton.  For the exact steps I followed. see the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me on x86_64-linux-gnu is to update from v6.9 to v7.1 and then use

`> convert a3x2.svg -scale 80x80 a3x2.png`

as expected.  More specifically, I downloaded `ImageMagick-7.1.0-60.tar.gz` from https://imagemagick.org/archive/ (there is also `ImageMagick.tar.gz` which presumably is the newest version, but I am not sure about that so that I downloaded 7.1 explicitly).

- Extract the sources:
  `tar xfz ImageMagick-7.1.0-60.tar.gz`
- Suppose the sources are at `/home/me/sources/ImageMagick-7.1.0-60`.  Create a build directory at `/home/me/build/imagemagick-7.1`.
- `cd` to the build directory and configure:
  `cd /home/me/build/imagemagick-7.1`
  `/home/me/sources/ImageMagick-7.1.0-60/configure --prefix=/home/me/install/imagemagick-7.1`
- Run `make` and then `make install`.
- Add the `/home/me/install/imagemagick-7.1/bin` directory to `PATH`, alternative use alias or links to point to the tools located there.

To my great surprise, I didn't get any dependency problems, and everything appears to work fine for now.  FYI, using the RPM packages did **not** work for me due to missing dependencies (≈50 of them).