# ImageMagick creating a RGB image from Grayscale image

Tags: imagemagick, tiff, imagemagick-convert

I have a 32-bit floating point TIFF image that when I try to adjust it with ImageMagick it creates a sRGB image. No matter what I've tried, I cannot adjust the image that creates a grayscale image. The odd thing is, I have other TIFF images created the same exact way from the same software, and they don't have the problem.

```
> identify grayImage.tif
grayImage.tif TIFF 4096x3283 4096x3283+0+0 32-bit Grayscale Gray 51.3417MiB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

If I run convert or magick without any adjustments, it writes a gray scale image. But if I try to adjust the levels or gamma, it writes a sRGB image:

```
> magick grayImage.tif -gamma 0.96 grayImageOut.tif

> identify grayImageOut.tif
grayImageOut.tif TIFF 4096x3283 4096x3283+0+0 32-bit sRGB 153.892MiB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

I've tried setting the color space to grayscale, but the resulting image is still RGB:

```
> magick grayImage.tif -gamma 0.96 -set colorspace Grayscale  grayImageOut.tif
```

I've tried extracting the R channel, and the output is still sRGB:

```
> magick grayImage.tif -gamma 0.96 -channel R -separate -set colorspace Grayscale grayImageOut.tif

> identify grayImageOut.tif
grayImageOut.tif TIFF 4096x3283 4096x3283+0+0 32-bit sRGB 153.892MiB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

How can I work around this issue and create a grayscale image?

Comment: If you are on IM 7, then use magick and magick identify, not convert and not identify. See https://imagemagick.org/script/defines.php for -define quantum:format=type.  Add that with the appropriate type before reading the input.

Comment: Thanks Fred! I am using IM7 and magick instead of convert, but I don't see a magick identify - I just have identify. I tried setting quantum to: `-define quantum:format=floating-point` but still outputs a RGB image. Also tried using `-depth 32` with the quantum option and by itself.

Comment: The porting docs explain to preface all tools but convert with magick.  See https://imagemagick.org/script/porting.php#cli.  Post a link to your 32-bit TIFF and I will take a look.

Comment: Thank you kindly for looking into it. It's here: http://3dtopo.com/grayImageTest.tif.zip please let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me with IM 7.1.1.21 on Mac OSX Ventura.  You need to add -type grayscale to the command as well as the defines in my comment.

```
magick -quiet -define quantum-format=floating-point -depth 32 grayImageTest.tif -gamma 0.96 -type grayscale x.tif
magick identify x.tif

x.tif TIFF 4096x3283 4096x3283+0+0 32-bit Grayscale Gray 51.2975MiB 0.000u 0:00.001
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works with 7.1.1 built from source on Ubuntu as well.

Comment: @JeshuaLacock For reasons I do not understand, the ImageMagick version on debian/Ubuntu is ancient and building ImageMagick is no fun. I generally use the ImageMagick on Alpine Linux under `docker` which is very current, has many delegates and can be created and run in under 5 seconds. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/75344784/2836621

Comment: Thanks but it was super-easy to build on Ubuntu 22.04. Just needed to run `./configure`, `./make`, `sudo ./make install` and `sudo ldconfig /usr/local/lib`